# How can I get the data of a rtcp packet in freeswitch?

Tags: c, rtp, freeswitch, rtcp

Recently I want to calculate the lossrate during a call in freeswitch,however,I can't find the way of read a rtcp packet.And what is the definition of flaws in freeswitch？